# Halt request when authentication fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def authenticate
    authenticate_player || render_unauthorized
  end

  def authenticate_player
    @player = Player.find_by(authentication_token: params[:token])
  end

  def render_unauthorized
    render json: 'Access Denied', status: :unauthorized and return
  end
```

Then in my PlayerController I have

class PlayersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_player, only: [:rank]

```
def rank
    ranked = PlayerRanker.rank(@player)

    if ranked
      render(json: { rank: ranked})
    else
      render(json: { error: 'Player not ranked' }, status: :not_found)
    end
  end
```

but when I send without an authentication token, the method proceeds because it returns the `:unauthorized` from `authenticate_player`.. then continues. How do I render and return and halt ALL returns?

Other examples I've looked up show putting the return inside each action. I want to use this in a separate method.

Answer (score 0):

`return` simply returns a value and halt the execution of the current function. What you want instead is to raise an exception.

```
# lib/errors.rb
class NotAuthorizedException < StdError; end
```

---

```
def authenticate_player
  @player = Player.find_by(authentication_token: params[:token])
  raise NotAuthorizedException, 'Not authorized to view Player' unless @player
end
```

Then in your `ApplicationController` you setup a [`rescue_from`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue-from) handler.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...
  rescue_from NotAuthorizedException, with: :not_authorized

  private

    def not_authorized
      render json: 'Access Denied', status: :unauthorized
    end
end
```

But if you are not creating your own authorization solution for the sake of learning I would recommend you use a library such as [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan).